# React Native Image URL lowers my performance

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview, react-native-image

When I display my images in the horizontal scroll-view with paging enabled the performance of app decreases. I know it is due to high resolution of the image. I want a good way so that I can load image with out degrading it's quality.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, using a `FlatList` instead of a scroll view will probably improve performance, since off-screen images will not be rendered.

Second, using images with resolution that is greater than the screen is just wasteful, since they will get resized anyway. You can pre-compute several sizes and use the most appropriate one computing the actual screen resolution using `PixelRatio`

```
var image = getImage({
  width: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(200),
  height: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(100),
});
<Image source={image} style={{width: 200, height: 100}} />
```

See the [`PixelRatio`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio) documentation for more detailed on fetching an appropriate size image.